# Storing regular expressions within a variable (std::string)

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to store a regular expression within a variable, i.e if we had a regular expression, `\\d` and a string, `std::string str;` then I would store the regular expression `\\d` within `std::string str`. From that I could then use `str` whenever I wanted to use that regular expression.

I tried something like this:

```
Boost::regex const string_matcher("\\d");
std::string str = string_matcher;
```

However I realized that it would not work. Does anyone have any ides of how I can store a regular expression?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. What's wrong with `std::string str = "\\d"; Boost::regex string_matcher(str);`

Comment: You really need [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642). *You have the solution to your own problem in the code you posted*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string regex = "\\d";
boost::regex expression(regex);
bool ok = boost::regex_match(testStr, expression);
```

Comment: I should have thought about this earlier, ok thanks for your help man

Comment: i don't see the check symbol unless im overlooking it :/

Answer (score 3):

You already have your regular expression stored in a variable. You called it `string_matcher`.